# Regex Cookie To Get PHPSESSID value

Tags: php, regex

I have a cookie with the following data:

```
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1315605660  lang    en
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1314223260  role    premium
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1314223260  PHPSESSID   7ah4ppb3bcbubged8pejb05s35
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1314223260  rememberMe  1
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1314223260  email   me@email.me
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1281477659  nickname    deleted
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1281477659  isAffiliate deleted
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   0   messagingUnread 0
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   0   messagingUnreadLastcheck    1313013660
```

I only want to get the value of the PHPSESSID which in this case is: 7ah4ppb3bcbubged8pejb05s35

How can I get that value using preg_match?

Update:

So here is the result of var_dump($cookie);

```
string '# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1315612275  lang    en
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1314229875  role    premium
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1314229875  PHPSESSID   j8v4ifqfpvbfr1cjp49e8del55
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1314229875  rememberMe  1
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1314229875  email   me%40email.me
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1281484274  nickname    deleted
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1281484274  isAffiliate deleted
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   0   messagingUnread 0
.somesite.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   0   messagingUnreadLastcheck    1313020275
' (length=647)
```

I tried this:

```
$search_expression = '/PHPSESSID\s+(.*)$/';
preg_match($search_expression, $cookie, $search_result);
```

And then I var_dump($search_result);

```
array
  empty
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: why are you directly accessing cookie files?

Comment: Why not simply read the `$_COOKIE` value or retrieve the session ID using PHP's built-in functions?

Comment: I am saving cookie values and accessing them in a background process which will use the PHPSESSID to download files from a protected site

Answer (score 2):

You may simply be using preg_match incorrectly. To populate a variable with the results of a search, it would look something like this:

```
$search_expression = '/PHPSESSID\s+(.*)$/';
preg_match($search_expression, $cookie, $search_result);
```

Then to reference the specific session ID you would reference `$search_result[1]`, which will match just what is in parentheses (the session ID). So to use this example, try this:

```
$search_expression = '/PHPSESSID\s+(.*)$/';
if (preg_match($search_expression, $cookie, $search_result)) {
  echo "PHP Session ID found.";
  $phpsessionid = $search_result[1];
} else {
  echo "PHP Session ID not found.";
}
```

This will help narrow down the problem. If nothing is still returning, then the problem is with the search expression. You might alternately try this if that is the case:

```
$search_expression = '/PHPSESSID\s+(.*)\s+\.some/';
```

And if that still doesn't work, try this search expression:

```
$search_expression = '/PHPSESSID\s+([a-z0-9]+)\s+\.some/';
```

Comment: yeah, I am not sure why it is not working. I updated my question above with new info.

Comment: As I said, the `$search_result` is an array, so to access only the PHP Session ID (the part of the search expression in parentheses), you need to reference it as `$search_result[1]`, which will return the first hit from an item in parentheses. If the array is returning nothing (empty), then the search expression is incorrect and is not working (not finding the PHP Session ID).

Comment: Yeah that did not work either. I solved the issue by first exploding by \n and then looping through each line to check for strstr PHPSESSID then if thats true I used this expression to get the value: /PHPSESSID\t+(.*)$/

Comment: OK, great! Glad it got solved. I'd recommend posting the solution as an answer so others can benefit from it. I'll be sure to vote it up. Then you can also mark it as the accepted answer and this will be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If the separator is a tab, or a space or both in a multi-line string:

```
~[ \t]PHPSESSID[ \t]+(.*)$~m
```

Comment: or just have \s+ instead of \t

Comment: `^` matches the beginning of the line. I think you mean `$`.

Comment: It is a \t character and after the PHPSESSID is a \n.

Comment: these did not work $value = preg_match("/PHPSESSID\t(.*)$/", $cookie);

Comment: The cookie value is one large string.

Comment: @gprim: You need the `m` (multiline) modifier then to make `$` match the end of line. Use the tab variant as `\s` matches line-breaks as well.

Comment: @hakre that did not do it. It's returning an empty array all the time...I guess i could split by each line and perform a regex on each line. But thats not optimal..

Comment: @gprime: Well your input is no really perfectly specified, maybe the tab is just more than one tab and/or space as well.